# How to clean white, sticky substance on headphone band?

Tags: cleaning, headphones

I have 9 months old Motorola Pulse Max Headphones. I used them rarely and always kept them in their original box. yesterday I took them out and noticed a white sticky substance on the handle part. (See images)

[image: Headphone Compile Image]
[image: Another dirty part]

my brother told me that the surface was tearing apart (or eroding) but I was not convinced.

Can anyone please suggest how to clean it?

Comment: Is there a chance that something you use for your hair care reacted with the material on the headphones? It appears that the surface is pitted. Is the sticky material on or under the surface? If the surface is broken, then there might be nothing to remove unless something is stuck to the unbroken surface.

Comment: @Stan well the only hair care product that i use is applying oil on head. thats it. the sticky surface is **on** the product. while taking out some of my hair stuck to it, i eroded some part of the material itelf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation: As the parts of the headband and earphone cushion where the hair touches the equipment is affected, I suspect that something you use in your hair has reacted with the materials used on your headphones.

If the surface is broken or pitted, there is little that can be repaired. You can try some pressure sensitive cloth tape to cover the area. If that is not acceptable, replacement is another alternative.

If the surface has some sticky material that can be removed, try a drop of mild detergent (blue Dawn has no additives and rinses cleanly) or your usual shampoo on a damp cloth to remove it. If that doesn't work, contact the manufacturer for their recommendation for the material they used.

Contact the manufacturer customer relations department for their opinion on how to proceed. Their knowledge base might have similar solutions to similar problems. Identify your hair care materials in the chance they have already had some experience with exactly the problem you identify.

It seems unlikely but possible that you can get a refund or replacement if there is something wrong with your equipment since it is relatively new and you have evidently taken excellent care of it.

Lastly, is there a chance that someone had a problem when they borrowed your headphones without your knowledge or permission.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Get some drops of isopropyl alchol and apply on it thoroughly until it became clean